# Show that $A^{n}\to0$ if and only if $\|A\|^{n}\to0$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Let $\boldsymbol{A}$ be a square matrix. Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\boldsymbol{A}^{n}=0$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|\boldsymbol{A}\|^{n}=0$ for the spectral radius  or for some operator norm.

Comment: Does the problem actually ask you to show this? It's not true. (To give a counterexample we need to know what definition of $||A||$ you're using...)

Comment: Only one side is always true, since $\|A^n\| \leq \|A\|^n$, then if $\|A\|^n \to 0$ then  $\|A^n\| \to 0$.

Comment: If you added "for some operator norm $\|\cdot\|$", then the result would be true since for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an operator norm $\|\cdot\|$ such that $\|A\|\leq\rho(A)+\epsilon$ and $A^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ iff $\rho(A)<1$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$ with the $l_1$ norm, then
$\|A\| = 1$. Since $A^2 = 0$, we see that $\lim_n \|A^n\| = 0$, but we have
$\lim_n \|A\|^n = 1$.

Comment: +1, great example. The  $l_2$ norm is also $1$,  the spectral radius is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The spectral radius is not a norm; one reason is because there are nonzero matrices all of whose eigenvalues are zero. (Such matrices can't be diagonalizable, but nondiagonalizable matrices exist!) copper.hat gave one example.

Your property *does* hold if you replace $\| \cdot \|$ with the spectral radius.

If $A^n \to 0$, then there *exists* a norm, which can be chosen to be induced by some vector norm, such that $\| A \|^n \to 0$. This is ultimately because $\rho(A)$ is the infimum of $\| A \|$ over all possible operator norms. One direction (that the spectral radius is a lower bound) is easy to see by homogeneity and the operator norm property. The other direction (that the spectral radius is the *greatest* lower bound) is harder to prove.

Comment: +1, you nailed the correct statement . Good to learn about the spectral radius! It seems that you can restrict to operator norms coming from some $l_2$ norm, and it's enough to reason on Jordan cell, which is not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

For $A$ matrix denote by $\rho(A)$ the spectral radius of $A$, $= \max \{ |\lambda_i|\}$, with $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

We have $A^n \to 0$ if and only  $\rho(A)^n \to 0$ if and only if $\rho(A)<1$.
For proof one can use the Jordan canonical form.

Now if $||\cdot ||$ is any algebra norm on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ ( for example coming from a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$), then $||A||< 1$ implies $A^n \to 0$, because $||A^n|| \le ||A||^n$. The converse is not true, as the example of 
@copper.hat: shows. The norm of the operator $A\colon e_1 \mapsto \alpha e_2 \mapsto 0$ can be made as large as wanted, while $A^2 = 0$.

Notes:

The spectral radius is not a norm for the algebra $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ if $n \ge 2$;  one can have $A$, $B$ nilpotent ( $\rho(A) = \rho(B) = 0$) and $\rho(AB) = $ large; take $A$ the one above, $B= A^{t}$.

If $A^n \to 0$ then the convergence is exponential. Moreover, the series $\sum_{n\ge 0} A^n$ is also covergent, with sum $(I-A)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

If use the norm for matrix as

> $$\|A\|=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|^2}$$

We can prove

> $$
> \|A\|^n \to 0\implies \|A^n\| \to 0
> $$
>   Converse is not true as a counter example is given by copper.hat.

First we prove the following:

> **Lemma:**
>   $\hspace{2 mm}\|AB\|\leqslant\|A\|\|B\|$

Prove:
\begin{align}
\|AB\|^2&=\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_{ik}b_{kj}\right|^2
\\
&\leqslant\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n|a_{ik}|^2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n|b_{kj}|^2\right)\tag{Cauchy-Schwarz}
\\
&=\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}\left(\sum\limits_{k,l=1}^n|a_{ik}|^2|b_{lj}|^2\right)
\\
&=\sum\limits_{i,k=1}^{n}|a_{ik}|^2\sum\limits_{l,j=1}^n|b_{lj}|^2
\\
&=\|A\|^2\|B\|^2
\\
\end{align}
Now by lemma
$$
\|A^n\|\leqslant\|A\|^n \hspace{5 mm} \text{and so} \hspace{5 mm} \|A^n\| \to 0\hspace{5 mm} \text{as} \hspace{5 mm} \|A\|^n\to 0
$$